# Find a substring in a string with for loops

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
function match(str1, str2) {
  var matched = false
  for (i in str1) {
    if (str1[i] == str2[0]) {
      for (j in str2) {
        if (str2[j] != str1[i]) {
          return false
        } else {
          i++
          matched = true
        }
      }

    }
    return matched
  }

}

console.log(match("umbrella", "rella"))
```

Can someone fix this code. Is this piece of code good enough. or any improvements. I wanted to find a string in another string with just using the for loops. I saw some answers but they were too complex.

Im a beginner

Answer (score 2):

You are returning after only one iteration, change

```
    }
    return matched
  }
}
```

to

```
    }
  }
  return matched
}
```

That being said, if I'm understanding your code correctly, right now it will fail if it starts to find a match, but then it doesn't match, and there is a match later.

E.g.

```
console.log(match("umbrerella", "rella"))
```

```js
function match(str1, str2) {
  var matched = false
top:
  for (i in str1) {
    if (str1[i] == str2[0]) {
      for (j in str2) {
        if (str2[j] != str1[i]) {
          matched = false
          continue top
        } else {
          i++
          matched = true
        }
      }
      if (matched) return true;

    }
  }
  return matched
}

console.log(match("umbrella", "rella"))
console.log(match("umbrella", "della"))
console.log(match("umbrerellas", "rella"))
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`for ... in` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) iterates over the own enumerable keys of the object. This could be handy for objects, but it does not work always for arrays ([Why is using "for...in" for array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1447675)).

Instead use a classic [`for` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) with an index variable from zero to less than the length.

---

You could take some short circuits and exit early on found and omit iterating over the lengths.

```js
function match(str1, str2) {
    for (let i = 0, l = str1.length - str2.length + 1; i < l; i++) {
        let match = true;
        for (let j = 0; match && j < str2.length; j++) {
            if (str1[i + j] !== str2[j]) match = false;
        }
        if (match) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(match("umbrella", "rella"));
console.log(match("umbrella", "rello"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just use:

```js
console.log("umbrella".includes("rella"))
```

Comment: I dont want to use any helper methods

Comment: The OP only wants to use for loops.